# Apache 2.4 Whitelist Cloudflare only

Tags: apache, cloudflare, apache2.4, whitelist, apache2.2

I've been trying to get this to work for Apache 2.4

I manually installed Apache 2.4, PHP 5.6, MySql, and MySqli. (I haven't had a problem with mysql since I've only been using MySqli)

I have tried to white list only cloudflare to access my website, but I haven't been having any luck and since their IP list doesn't give me absolutely everything I need, I can't white list them.

I know that I shouldn't white list only cloudflare, but I accidentally shared the IP to someone and they spread it around, and I don't want them using the ip directly, I want them to use cloudflare.

I've tried doing this to white list cloudflare but it hasn't been working:

`<Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/test">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require all denied
    Allow from 103.21.*.*
    Allow from 103.31.*.*
    Allow from 103.22.*.*
    Allow from 104.16.*.*
    Allow from 108.162.*.*
    Allow from 131.0.*.*
    Allow from 141.101.*.*
    Allow from 162.158.*.*
    Allow from 172.64.*.*
    Allow from 173.245.*.*
    Allow from 188.114.*.*
    Allow from 190.93.*.*
    Allow from 197.234.*.*
    Allow from 198.41.*.*
    Allow from 199.27.*.*
</Directory>`

I havn't fully understood the jump from 2.2 to 2.4 yet. Could anybody help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install the Mod_Cloudflare Apache extension, you can simply add the following to your Apache configuration and all non-Cloudflare traffic will be forbidden:

```
DenyAllButCloudFlare
```

Further reading:

- [Logging Real Visitor IP Addresses: mod_cloudflare for Apache httpd](https://www.cloudflare.com/technical-resources/#mod_cloudflare)

Comment: How do I get this for Debian 8 Jesse 32 bit?

Comment: See Debian instructions here: https://www.cloudflare.com/technical-resources/#mod_cloudflare

Comment: It only exists for 32 bit however, wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: 64 bit binaries are listed there, but there are also instructions there for building the module yourself using Apache itself running apxs or apxs2 commands.

Answer (score -1):

Though I am not 100% sure this answer is appropriate to your question but I will share it in case some other people want different solution.

Cloudflare pass a real ip in  `HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP`. So we can setup Rewrite(using mod_rewrite). So we don't need to whitelist cloudflare's ips, accept all ip and check the `HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP`. If there is no match, we deny. So the configuration in wordpress conf is as following. The example shows any real ip not starting with 17.133.218 is denied access.

```
    <Directory /var/www/wordpress>
            Options -Indexes
       <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-CONNECTING-IP} !^17\.133\.218\.
            RewriteRule $ /maintenance [R=302,L]
       </IfModule>
    </Directory>
```